# How to Write a Comparision between value in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I want to compare the value between the syntax code `"userName()"` and `STRToMember("[xxxx].[Username].&[" + UserName() + "]")` in SSAS:s calculation, inside of a calculated member.

Unfortunately, I get error message. How should I write the code to make comparision.

```
IIF
(
    userName() = STRToMember("[xxxx].[Username].&[" + UserName() + "]"),
    "yes",
    "No"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the error is ? 'coz the following code is running with no issue and as expected return 'no' (edit after FrankPI comment : note the usage of .NAME for example ) :

```
with member [Measures].[xx] as 

IIF
(
    userName() = STRToMember("[Customer].[Country].&[" + UserName() + "]").NAME,
    "yes",
    "No"
)


select from [Adventure Works] where [Measures].[xx]
```

Comment: This code is good in context to management studio but does this code work to be used in  SSAS:s calculation, inside of a calculated member?

Comment: When you brwose in SSAS and use the code for the calculated measure the value will say "No"

Comment: Sorry explain to us how you're using your IIF and give us the error message so that we can reply effectively. Yes this code works in a calc. measure => [xx] is a calc. measure

Comment: I think formally it works. But it probably does not do what @FullMetalGame intends to do (he never told us what this is). Actually, what it does is compare the user name string (something like "mydomain\myname") to the value of the current measure for the member named like the user name in the country hierarchy. And if the current measure in the context where this is evaluated happens to be e. g. something numeric, then obviously, the result is "No". In @MarcPolizzi's answer, the current measure is `xx`, which AS sets to NULL in the definition of itself to avoid infinite recursion.

Comment: @FrankPI : oops you're right for the actual value; missed that one. I've updated a bit my response.